# Data not sending to api using http post

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I want to post json data to an api, but the api not receive the data from the app, although I tested the api from php script and it work fine. " I Think the problem in Content-Type : application/json" but I set it in the code. Any Solutions?

[BackEnd Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBx2w.jpg)

```
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "username": "some data",
  "password": "some data",
  "mobile": "some data",
  "hash": "some data"
}'
```

Flutter code :

```
static Future<String> createNewUser(String url,{String body}) async{
    Map<String,String> headers = {
      "Content-type" : "application/json",
    };
    return await http.post(url,body: body,headers: headers).then((http.Response response){
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
      print(response.body);
        if( json == null){
          throw new Exception("Error while create new account");
        }
        return response.body;
    });
  }
```

Encoded json

```
CreateUser createUser  = new CreateUser(
              username: "someData",
              password:"someData",
              mobile: "someData",
              hash: Validation.generateHash("someData"),
            );

            var body = json.encode(createUser.toMap());
            CreateUser.createNewUser(Config.URL_CREATE_NEW_USER,body: body).then((res){
              print(res);
```

Comment: Do you get any response from the http.post call?

Comment: @ArthurThompson yes,  the response from api that there is no data was sent.

Comment: The code looks correct, I'd verify that the body that arrives at createNewUser is not empty and is valid json.

Comment: @ArthurThompson, createNewUser not empty I printed it and is generating valid json

Comment: Maybe your backend code is not reading the body correctly.

Comment: @ArthurThompson, I tested the backend from php script and it is work fine.

Answer (score 0):

try not to use `await` and `then` together on one `Future` value.

try following:

```
static Future<String> createNewUser(String url,{String body}) async{
    Map<String,String> headers = {
      "Content-type" : "application/json",
    };
    http.Response response = await http.post(url,body: body,headers: headers)
    final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    print(response.body);
    if( json == null){
      throw new Exception("Error while create new account");
    }
    return response.body;
  }
```

Comment: no results also after using your function, in all cases server respond by code 1010, it is mean that the data not sent to api. I think the problem in backend in receiving the json data

Comment: oh, okay. no problem

Comment: Thanks my friend for your help